# CSS3 Shapes - How can I do a mixture of Trapezoid-like shape with transparent bg and 1px border

Tags: css

[image: shape that I want to draw using CSS3]

My client wants me to do a similar thing on his website. On the front page I did a similar thing where there was color in the background and there's no border around the shape. But in the inner pages, there is a transparent color on the bg and a border on outside of the shape.

Here's the home page:
[image: Homepage using CSS3 shapes]

The home page is nicely done using CSS3. But as you know that, the CSS3 shapes are mostly done using borders ([I'm using this tutorial^](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)). For the homepage, where there's no border, I did it. But in the inner pages, with:

```
    .head-top{
      background: none;
      border-right: 1px solid #ededed; /* light color for testing, but it'd be #fff */
      border-left: 50px solid transparent;
      height: 0;
      width: 800px;
    }
```

I's unable to draw the outer lines of the transparent or white Trapezoid-like shape. I tried with:

```
    .head-top:before{
      content: '';
      border-top: 1px solid #000;
      border-left: 1px solid #000;
      border-right: 1px solid #000;
      display: block;
    }
```

But with this I's just able to draw the top border only. How can I proceed with such critical shape using CSS3?

Yes, I know I can do it easily using image, and I'm a graphics designer also. But actually I want to learn something new from the CSS3 enthusiasts. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a redo, and probably the best I'll be able to do.

Hopefully you'll be able to tweak it, or get some ideas from it.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/wBYN8/)

HTML

```
<div class='holder'>
    <div class='tallsquare'></div>
    <div class='smallsquare'></div>
    <div class='bigsquare'></div>
    <div class='anglesquare'></div>
    <div class='littleyellowcircle'></div>
    <div class='bigredcircle'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice fiddle. Actually I need it transparent or fill with #fff where the whole shape contains a border (ref.: image- top one). I failed there.

Comment: I made the homepage using 3 <div>s (http://prntscr.com/2mz044), and applied pseudo classes only on the top <div> (#1).

Comment: Tried with box-shadow, but not working good on the pseudo elements. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are targeting CSS3 browsers, that can help you:

HTML

```
<div class="base">
  <div class="rotated">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.base {
   position: absolute;
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
   left: 100px;
   top: 150px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.rotated {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: solid 1px green;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 325px;
    transform-origin: 100% 325px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 396px;
    height: 297px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: solid 1px green;
    background-color: rgba(255, 252, 192, 0.52);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 24px;
    transform-origin: 100% 24px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

The first div sets an overflow hidden for the next one. (and has the dimensions that you final div will have).

The rotated div is rotated 45 deg so that its border can draw the diagonal border. The remaining border of this div is hidden by previous overflow hidden.

And the inner div is the real one (that you have now). It can have a background set without problem because the rotated div is also clipping it.

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/Eq6wA/)

In the fiddle, the body has an stripped background, that can be seen thru the semitransparent background of your element.

Note that the dimensions are critical. The wrong size and the borders will not match !

Comment: This out-of-box solution was a good try too. But I'm afraid that'd be a mess. Anyways, thanks for the nice try. That helped me to understand the inner concepts too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TimSPQR for his patient try. His code gave me the idea of proceeding. I did with 5 `<div>`s of my structure. And taken idea of stacking `<div>`s with proper position from this [CSS-Tricks article^](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/).

```
    <header>
    <div class="header-holder">
        <div class="box-angle"></div>
        <div class="box-top-right"></div>
        <div class="box-left-mini"></div>
    </div>
    <header>
    <content></content>
```

[**Here's my fiddle^**](http://jsfiddle.net/wzislam/Pg5Ah/).

I used the `<content>` container for the bottom part.

This was a nice try for me to understand this types of shapes, and thanks to our cardiologist for his cardio-look into the HTML `<div>`s :). That's why I marked his answer as "Accepted".